# Why Chrome get frozon with role="textbox" attribute?

Tags: html, google-chrome, role

Chrome crashes with role="textbox" attribute while two divisions in same hierarchy with display:inline-block.

```
Test
<div id="single-input" style="width: 200px; height: 25px; display: inline-block;" role="textbox">
  <input id="textInput"/>
  <div id="btn">
     <div style="width:18px;height:18px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;"></div>

<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Here is the sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/3a3Rh/

Opera also crashes while IE and FF work fine.

I guess it is chrome related bug.

Please, let me know what exactly causes chrome freezing.

Thanks.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't make Chrome or Opera crash on my computer... Perhaps your browsers need to be updated?

Comment: My chrome version is 36.0.1985.125m 32bit. :(  I reported it to chrome . Some PCs work fine, but several have same problem - chrome crash. I prefer <input type="text"/> rather than <input role="textbox"/>. I guess it dose not cause semantic confusions.

Comment: I figured out solution. Web accessibility APIs are heavily dependent on your OS. So, If you have any security programs running background on your OS, please, check that out whether they prevent to call your OS API or not.